# VS Code source control does not reflect GIT changes

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I use a MacOS laptop on Ventura(13.0.1) and I use VS code version 1.74.3 (Universal), When I make changes in my Vscode, the source control panel is not reflecting the changes I made and the notification centre of VScode shows the below error:

[image]

When I check the Vscode Developer Logs, I see the following errors

```
2023-01-24 20:03:13.166 [error] [File Watcher (parcel)] Unexpected error: No such file or directory (EUNKNOWN) (path: /Users/UserName/Desktop/folder)
2023-01-24 20:03:13.167 [error] [File Watcher (universal)] restarting watcher after error: No such file or directory
2023-01-24 20:03:13.918 [error] [File Watcher (parcel)] Unexpected error: No such file or directory (EUNKNOWN) (path: /Users/UserName/Desktop/folder)
2023-01-24 20:03:13.919 [error] [File Watcher (universal)] restarting watcher after error: No such file or directory
```

I have tried deleting VS code applications and also deleted the folders at `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code` and `~/.vscode` still the same error.

Comment: Does the file/directory at `/Users/UserName/Desktop/folder` exist if you manually open it?

Comment: @A_A Yes the folder exists

Comment: Just curious, does this happen in a different folder that has git? Also, does this happen in a different folder that has no git at all?

Comment: @Damzaky Yes, it happens in different folder with GIT.

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue ticket on their VS Code GitHub repo instead of asking here.

Comment: Could this be because VSCode workspace trust settings are in Restricted Mode for this folder? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust

Comment: reinstall vscode